# How to correctly create a thumbnail using C#?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, stream, memorystream

I have a console application written using `C#` on the top of Core .NET 2.2 framework.

I want to create asynchronous Task that would write a full-size image to storage. Additionally, the process will need to create a thumbnail and write it to the default storage.

Follow is the method that processes the logic. I documented each line to explain that I believe is happening

```
// This method accepts FileObject and returns a task
// The generated task will write the file as is to the default storage
// Then it'll create a thumbnail of that images and store it to the default storage
public async Task ProcessImage(FileObject file, int thumbnailWidth = 250)
{
    // The name of the full-size image
    string filename = string.Format("{0}{1}", file.ObjectId, file.Extension);

    // The name along with the exact path to the full-size image
    string path = Path.Combine(file.ContentId, filename);

    // Write the full-size image to the storage
    await Storage.CreateAsync(file.Content, path)
                 .ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        // Reset the stream to the beginning since this will be the second time the stream is read
        file.Content.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        // Create original Image
        Image image = Image.FromStream(file.Content);

        // Calulate the height of the new thumbnail
        int height = (thumbnailWidth * image.Height) / image.Width;

        // Create the new thumbnail
        Image thumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(thumbnailWidth, height, null, IntPtr.Zero);

        using (MemoryStream thumbnailStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Save the thumbnail to the memory stream
            thumb.Save(thumbnailStream, image.RawFormat);

            // The name of the new thumbnail
            string thumbnailFilename = string.Format("thumbnail_{0}", filename);

            // The name along with the exact path to the thumbnail
            string thumbnailPath = Path.Combine(file.ContentId, thumbnailFilename);

            // Write the thumbnail to storage
            Storage.CreateAsync(thumbnailStream, thumbnailPath);
        }

        // Dispose the file object to ensure the Stream is disposed
        file.Dispose();
        image.Dispose();
        thumb.Dispose();
    });
}
```

Here is my `FileObject` if needed

```
public class FileObject : IDisposable
{
    public string ContentId { get; set; }
    public string ObjectId { get; set; }
    public ContentType ContentType { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public Stream Content { get; set; }
    private bool IsDisposed;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (IsDisposed)
            return;

        if (disposing && Content != null)
        {
            Content.Close();
            Content.Dispose();
        }

        IsDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

The above code writes the correct full-size image to the storage drive. It also writes the thumbnail to storage. However, the thumbnail is always corrupted. In other words, the generated thumbnail file is always written with 0 bytes.

How can I correctly create my thumbnail from `file.Content` stream after writing the same stream to the storage?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the cause of the issue. For some reason the line `thumb.Save(thumbnailStream, image.RawFormat);` position the `thumbnailStream` at the end and when writing to the storage nothing gets written

Fixing that issues was to reset the seek position after writing to the stream like this

```
    using (MemoryStream thumbnailStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Save the thumbnail to the memory stream
        thumb.Save(thumbnailStream, image.RawFormat);

        // Reset the seek position to the begining
        thumbnailStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        // The name of the new thumbnail
        string thumbnailFilename = string.Format("thumbnail_{0}", filename);

        // The name along with the exact path to the thumbnail
        string thumbnailPath = Path.Combine(file.ContentId, thumbnailFilename);

        // Write the thumbnail to storage
        Storage.CreateAsync(thumbnailStream, thumbnailPath);
    }
```

I am not sure what is the benefit that is gained when `thumb.Save(...)` does not reset the position to 0 after copying into a new stream! I just feel that it should be doing that since it will always write a new stream not appending to an existing one.